# How to get entire column from database to file?

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to develop a short code that allows me to get the entire data from on column from a table to a .txt file.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE status = :status");
    $query->execute(array(":status" => "1"));
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/files/".$date=date("d-m-Y")."-newsletter.txt";
    $openf = fopen($file, "w");
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= "".$row["email"].",";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
    fwrite($openf, $current);
    fclose($openf);
}
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($file);
```

this is what i have so far, but the main problem is that it only prints 1 line to the .txt file, whether it should print at least 2.
Anyone can help me solve this? I've tried different methods and none worked so far.

Comment: you don't have to save a file. you can echo your data right away

Comment: that said, you are overwriting your file on every iteration

Comment: how so? I create a file and after it's downloaded it's automatically deleted.

Comment: ...and doing it twice

Comment: and there is absolutely no point in creating a file and then deleting it. Well, unless there is several megabytes of data.

Comment: yeah, that's the point, this will be a newsletter table, so there will come a time when it's full of data, which can be somewhat heavy to just echo it. but i fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the file before loop and save after loop

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE status = :status");
$query->execute(array(":status" => "1"));
//create file
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/files/".$date=date("d-m-Y")."-newsletter.txt";
$openf = fopen($file, "w");
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "".$row["email"].",";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
//save and close
fwrite($openf, $current);
fclose($openf);
...
```